# Usability of a found OTP Token for my own system

Tags: one-time-password, token

I found a one-time-password token and am unable to find out who it belongs to or where it has been used.

It seems to be manufactured by a company called "ActivIdentity" (now "HID") and called the "keychain"-model. This is what it looks like:

[image: ActivIdentity Keychain-model]

It requested a PIN (which I obviously not know), and after I tried several random numbers it locked completely. Looking at the online manual for users of the token, the token must be given to the user's company's IT-administrator to be reinitialized, which I of course don't have. As far as I could find out, one possibility for the administrator would be to initialize it with the "ActivIdentity AAA-Server", which I also don't have.

Now I hope to be able to use it for my own systems (e.g. authentication for my ssh-access on my own server). In order to do this, I need to initialize it.

- Is there any known way to initialize the key with software available to private users?
- Is there any know possibility to use this for already available online services?

Comment: This isn't an InfoSec question. This is very specific to this company's device.

Comment: Why not use another OTP option? http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Actividentity requires a initalization rig/cradle to be initalized with a key.
A actividentity initialization rig/cradle looks like a plate with 2 Sharp Nails on. Those Nails are put through the label on the back. you can propably see 2 small pinholes in the back label with a blank Surface below. Those are electrical Contacts used for "loading" the token with keys.

However, theres other tokens out there that can be bought if you need to secure access to your server.

I would however, not recommend a software token. It can be too easly copied.

Answer (score 0):

No.

In order to validate the token, you need some software and/or hardware and/or an online account. You may also need a key which might have been configured locally.